# Convert Shell Output into Array

Tags: powershell

im trying to get the mac address table from a switch with plink (putty)

i got this code:

```
$psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
...
$plink = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi);
...
$output = $plink.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

i got the mac-table as string output (table) like:

```
[1;24r[24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1H192-168-1-110--2930-48POE# [24;1H[24;28H[24;
1H[?25h[24;28H[1;0H[1M[24;1H[1L[24;28H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[1;24r[
24;1H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1H192-168-1-110--2930-48POE# [24;1H[24;28H[24;1H[?25h
[24;28H[1;0H[1M[24;1H[1L[24;28H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[24
;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1H192-168-1-110--2930-48POE# [24;1H[24;28H[24;1H[?25h[24;28H[
1;0H[1M[24;1H[1L[24;28H[24;1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H[24;1H[2K[
24;1H[?25h[24;1H[24;1H192-168-1-110--2930-48POE# [24;1H[24;28H[24;1H[?25h[24;28H[24;28Hsho
w mac-a[24;28H[?25h[24;38H[24;38Hddress[24;38H[?25h[24;44H[1;0H[1M[24;1H[1L[24;44H[24;
1H[2K[24;1H[?25h[24;1H[1;24r[24;1H
 Status and Counters - Port Address Table

  MAC Address       Port                            VLAN
  ----------------- ------------------------------- ----
  000f23-b92gc3     Trk1                            1  
  ....
```

Is it possible to get the mac-table as array or at least as raw string (only the table)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement:

```bash
$dataLinesReached = $false
$propNames = 'MacAddress', 'Port', 'Vlan'
switch -Regex ($output.TrimEnd() -split '\r?\n') {
  '^\s*-----' { $dataLinesReached = $true; continue }
  default {
    if (-not $dataLinesReached) { continue }
    $aux = [ordered] @{} # aux. ordered hashtable for collecting key-value pairs
    $fields = -split $_  # split by whitespace
    # Populate the hashtable based on the field values.
    foreach ($i in 0..($propNames.Count-1)) { $aux[$propNames[$i]] = $fields[$i] }
    [pscustomobject] $aux # convert to [pscustomobject] and output
  }
}
```

This yields `[pscustomobject]` instances with `.MacAddress`, `.Port` and `.Vlan` properties; sample display output:

```
MacAddress    Port Vlan
----------    ---- ----
000f23-b92gc3 Trk1 1
```

Comment: this works good but i get this "[24;1H[2K-- MORE --, " in some rows

Comment: @Elias, the output seemingly contains ANSI / Virtual Terminal escape sequences meant to produce colored output. These escape sequences get in the way of programmatic parsing. While you could try to strip with a regex-based string-replacement operation first, doing so robustly is difficult. It's much better to suppress creation of these escape sequences at the source, but to that end we'd need to know the specifics of the plink call you're making.